# How should we document version tags like tridion-2011

Tags: discussion, tags

I proposed the following Tag Wiki Excerpt  for the `tridion-2011` tag:

> SDL Tridion 2011 is the name of the SDL Tridion Content Management System released in 2010

and the following description:

> Versions released as SDL Tridion 2011 are 2011 GA (with on top of that HR1) and 2011 SP1 (with on top of that SP1 HR1).

They have been rejected with the following comment: *This edit does not follow any of our [tag wiki guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) and is unlikely to help instruct future visitors in the appropriate use of the tag.*

So what would a good description be for a version tag?

Answer (score 7):

This is how [Drupal does it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7).

I like the simplicity of the tag, just "7". Should we do the same with Tridion and just use 2009, 2011, 2013 instead of tridion-2009, tridion-2011, tridion-2013.

Comment: I like that idea as well.

Comment: so then we should document it something like: This tag is for questions regarding SDL Tridion 2011 specifically. Version tags should be used only when strictly necessary, and not used just to report "I am using SDL Tridion 2011 in my site."

Comment: Check the full info for the tag, it also includes version requirements, and some installation notes: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/7/info

Comment: [SharePoint Exchange does the same](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags) with versions such as `2007` and `2010`.

Comment: What about questions with two products? For example SDL Tridion 2011 HR1 with SiteEdit 2009 SP3. WorldServer, SmartTarget, and other "add-ons" have their own version numbers.