# How should we document tags for questions mentioning specific service packs or hotfix rollups?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [How should we document version tags like Tridion-2011](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/how-should-we-document-version-tags-like-tridion-2011) we decided to use just product version numbers such as [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) or [5.3](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.3) for tags related to specific versions of a Tridion product.

At the time we didn't explicitly discuss whether we wanted to have tags for specific service packs or hot fix rollups although I think it was implicit in [Nuno's answer](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31/39) we would just tag them with the major version number of the product.

Recently we've had three questions tagged with [5.2sp1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.2sp1). My inclination is they should be retagged as [5.2](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.2) but I wanted to see what everyone else thinks first.

What should the tag convention be for questions mentioning specific service packs or hotfix rollups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree to retagging [5.2sp1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.2sp1) with [5.2](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.2) since else we are going to create a lot of version specific tags which do not necessarily add more clarity. The tag has the goal to group questions for a specific version, in the question text it should always be mentioned what version the question is specifically relating too (in which case I specifically mean service packs).

However we can't stop new users from creating such tags, so perhaps we should start ourselves with adding the known versions in there and suggest a clear tag wiki for them, so hopefully new users will choose those over others.

next we should start working on our FAQ and make this very clear in there. Something like: tagging is for grouping your question. And also explain the usage of version specific tags in there.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said here. In terms of working on our FAQ page, the only section we can change is the section on 'What kinds of questions can I ask here' BUT we can have moderators tag questions here in meta with the FAQ tag which there is a link to in the 'What if I need more help' section of the FAQ.

Comment: Bart, I added the 5.2 tag and retagged the questions. Also submitted a suggested basic tag wiki entry for 5.2. I don't have the information about release date of 5.2 or the service pack like you and Nuno provided for the 2011 tag wiki. Do you have something on that lines you can add for 5.2?