# Shouldn't we get rid of year numbers in tags?

Tags: discussion

I'm afraid that setting a year number in the tag can be too obvious and too easy for newcomers. Shouldn't we use product numbers, like `6.1` for 2011SP1, instead to give us some more space to flame the askers with proper tags?

Comment: What does 'give us some more space to flame the askers with proper tags' mean?

Comment: Have you heard of fools day?

Comment: It's clear this was an April Fool's joke after the fact. Not that we would, but let's be sure we don't tease actual askers with [answers that joke about procedures](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idp30009456). I think the most humorous part is the "Mr. P" imposter got stuck with the name for a month. :-P

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything we can do to change the fact that the version of SDL Tridion is done with the year of release. Even though internally there is a version number used, I don't think we should deviate from what is communicated externally.

Marking a question with [6.1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6.1) would be just as good or bad as marking it with [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011), the only difference being is that with [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) most will understand its related to SDL Tridion 2011, not everybody knows the internal version numbering.

We [discussed](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/how-should-we-document-version-tags-like-tridion-2011) if we should use [tridion-2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tridion-2011) or [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) and decided to follow [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags) and go with tag simplicity.

I don't agree that just a few of the questions tagged with [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) actually are about SDL Tridion 2011, for me it gives a clear reference that this version is being used, where the answer could be different if it was about version 2009 or 2013. Right now [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) will become a highly used tag, because most customers are on that version, but I think we will see a rise of the [2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2013) questions soon with the fresh release. That to me gives enough meaning and concept to that tag.

I tend to agree that the version tags might not be very useful for search engines, on the other hand a question about a different version might not always lead you in the right direction. So i'm definitely not in favor of changing [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) to something like [6.1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6.1) (and still think that [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) is better than [tridion-2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tridion-2011)) but agree that on some questions it might be valid to remove the tag.

> In reference of the day you posted this, yes the joke is on me :D

Answer (score 2):

There's an inherent problem with these vague, overused tags — they hurt the search engine findability of your content. Search is the lifeblood of this site, and your top tags rarely describe the question at all.

As much as you [say](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011) *"Version tags should be used **only** when necessary to provide context to the question, and not to simply state that you are using SDL Tridion 2011"*, they are becoming the most [over]used tags on the site.

Very few of these questions are actually *about* (for example) Tridion 2011 issues, specifically. Ideally, tags should identify the **top key concepts** in your question, and rarely does the version number do that. And to make matters worse, nobody outside this site is going to be searching for "2011" to find your content. All you've done is create a small collection of catch-all tags that apply to just about every question.

I agree that these tags should be renamed to something more descriptive. See if perhaps the approach Magento took is better suited to your product version labeling — https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags. But longer term, I would consider removing these tags where they are not truly one of the top concepts in the question.